# How to keep a reference alive in outside of a block (ARC Enabled)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

My question is about keeping a reference alive outside of a completion handler block. 
First, Please look at my TableViewController:

```
@interface KMTweetTableViewController : 
UITableViewController

@property (weak) ACAccount      
 *selectedAccount;

@property  NSMutableArray  *tweetTextBank ;

@end
```

In the `- (void)viewDidLoad` Method of `KMTweetTableViewController` I created a `SLRequest` instance named `userTimeLineRequest`. As it turns out, it is responsible for requesting twitter for the user's Timeline.

Then, I tried to make an array from statuses "text" property. I used this piece of code to do that:

```
[userTimeLineRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSArray *userTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:Nil];
            int counter ; NSMutableArray *returner = [NSMutableArray alloc]  ;
            for (counter= 1 ; counter <= userTimelineCountReference ; counter++) {
                NSDictionary  *status = [userTimeline objectAtIndex: counter-1]   ;
                NSString  *tweetText = [status objectForKey:@"text"];
                [self.tweetTextBank addObject:tweetText ];
            }
            NSLog(@"%@" , self.tweetTextBank) ;
        });

    }];
```

The code in `dispath_async` block works well but when `NSLog()` fires, I just get `null`. I think this is because the reference of `tweetText`s get terminated at the end of `dispath_async` block... So what can I do in this case to keep that reference alive when ARC is enabled?

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have not initialized the array so you are getting null. So first you need to initialize the mutable array.

```
self.tweetTextBank=[NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialise the mutablearray properly then add objects to it

```
self.tweetTextBank=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
[userTimeLineRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSArray *userTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:Nil];
            int counter ; 
            for (counter= 1 ; counter <= userTimelineCountReference ; counter++) {
                NSDictionary  *status = [userTimeline objectAtIndex: counter-1];
                NSString  *tweetText = [status objectForKey:@"text"];
                [self.tweetTextBank addObject:tweetText ];
            }
            NSLog(@"%@" , self.tweetTextBank) ;
        });

    }];
```